# Passing input text from 3 fields to a JavaScript and sending

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to send data capture info using a form that is linked to my CRM. The form is at the end of a video.

I have managed to get the fields to pass to the CRM and store the data but I can not get the Final Field, Company name to pass into the CRM.
I added in the extra Javascript to see if it would work onfocusout but it does not work. The other field pass in ok, even with the extra script being added.

I want all fields to pass to the crm, the Company should be a merge of First Name, Surname and (Email address), so

```
FN - John
SN - Smith
Email - js@google.com
Company would equal - John Smith(js@google.com)
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("First Name").value + " " + document.getElementById("Surname").value + "(" + document.getElementById("agilefield-9").value + ")";
  document.getElementById("agilefield-11").value = x;
}



(function(a) {
  var b = a.onload,
    p = true;
  isCaptcha = false;
  if (p) {
    a.onload = "function" != typeof b ? function() {
      try {
        _agile_load_form_fields()
      } catch (a) {}
    } : function() {
      b();
      try {
        _agile_load_form_fields()
      } catch (a) {}
    }
  };
  var formLen = document.forms.length;
  for (i = 0; i < formLen; i++) {
    if (document.forms.item(i).getAttribute("id") == "agile-form") {
      a.document.forms.item(i).onsubmit = function(a) {
        a.preventDefault();
        try {
          _agile_synch_form_v5(this)
        } catch (b) {
          this.submit()
        }
      }
    }
  }
})(window);
```

```html
<form class="form-view theme2" id="agile-form" action="https://***/formsubmit" style="max-width:450px;" method="GET">
  <fieldset>
    <!-- Form Name -->
    <legend class="agile-hide-formname">Membership Form</legend>
    <p class="agile-form-description">Please fill out your Membership form</p>
    <div style="display: none; height: 0px; width: 0px;">
      <input type="hidden" id="_agile_form_name" name="_agile_form_name" value="Membership Form">
      <input type="hidden" id="_agile_domain" name="_agile_domain" value="***">
      <input type="hidden" id="_agile_api" name="_agile_api" value="***">
      <input type="hidden" id="_agile_redirect_url" name="_agile_redirect_url" value="#">
      <input type="hidden" id="_agile_document_url" name="_agile_document_url" value="">
      <input type="hidden" id="_agile_confirmation_msg" name="_agile_confirmation_msg" value="Thanks">
      <input type="hidden" id="_agile_form_id_tags" name="tags" value="Video Form">
      <input type="hidden" id="_agile_form_id" name="_agile_form_id" value="***">
    </div>
    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="agile-group">
      <label class="agile-label" for="First Name">First Name</label>
      <div class="agile-field-xlarge agile-field">
        <input maxlength="250" id="First Name" name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="agile-height-default">
      </div>
      <div class="agile-custom-clear"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="agile-group">
      <label class="agile-label" for="Last Name">Last Name</label>
      <div class="agile-field-xlarge agile-field">
        <input maxlength="250" id="Last Name" name="last_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="agile-height-default">
      </div>
      <div class="agile-custom-clear"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="agile-group">
      <label class="agile-label" for="agilefield-9">Email</label>
      <div class="agile-field-xlarge agile-field">
        <input maxlength="250" id="agilefield-9" name="email" type="email" placeholder="" class="agile-height-default" onfocusout="myFunction()">
      </div>
      <div class="agile-custom-clear"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Hidden input-->
    <div class="agile-group agile-hiddenEle-group">
      <label class="agile-label" for="agilefield-11">Company</label>
      <div class="agile-field-xlarge agile-field">
        <input id="agilefield-11" name="Company" type="text" value="" class="agile-height-default">
      </div>
      <div class="agile-custom-clear"></div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: `id` can't have whitespace

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo Yes it can. Class names cannot

Comment: what is _agile_synch_form_v5? and does it give console errors?

Comment: Agile_synch_form_v5 is the version of the form that the CRM, agilecrm created.

Comment: I am not sure if it gives console errors, but it does sync most of the fields in as needed.

Comment: So this is a typo. You need "Last Name" or rename Last Name to Surname. Feel free to delete the question

Comment: many thanks, however although I added that a solution was found, in fact it does not work as it should, but thank you for the critical and very useful(not) feedback about it being a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are calling an element with id `Surname` which does not exist, you might be thinking about element with id `Last Name`.

> **Also important**, id's are unique and should not contain whitespace.

Replacing all of the id's in your code ("First Name" to "First-Name") this is how the code working looks like:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("First-Name").value + " " + document.getElementById("Last-Name").value + "(" + document.getElementById("agilefield-9").value + ")";
  document.getElementById("agilefield-11").value = x;
}



(function(a) {
  var b = a.onload,
    p = true;
  isCaptcha = false;
  if (p) {
    a.onload = "function" != typeof b ? function() {
      try {
        _agile_load_form_fields()
      } catch (a) {}
    } : function() {
      b();
      try {
        _agile_load_form_fields()
      } catch (a) {}
    }
  };
  var formLen = document.forms.length;
  for (i = 0; i < formLen; i++) {
    if (document.forms.item(i).getAttribute("id") == "agile-form") {
      a.document.forms.item(i).onsubmit = function(a) {
        a.preventDefault();
        try {
          _agile_synch_form_v5(this)
        } catch (b) {
          this.submit()
        }
      }
    }
  }
})(window);
```

```html
<form class="form-view theme2" id="agile-form" action="https://***/formsubmit" style="max-width:450px;" method="GET">
  <fieldset>
    <!-- Form Name -->
    <legend class="agile-hide-formname">Membership Form</legend>
    <p class="agile-form-description">Please fill out your Membership form</p>
    <div style="display: none; height: 0px; width: 0px;">
      <input type="hidden" id="_agile_form_name" name="_agile_form_name" value="Membership Form">
      <input type="hidden" id="_agile_domain" name="_agile_domain" value="***">
      <input type="hidden" id="_agile_api" name="_agile_api" value="***">
      <input type="hidden" id="_agile_redirect_url" name="_agile_redirect_url" value="#">
      <input type="hidden" id="_agile_document_url" name="_agile_document_url" value="">
      <input type="hidden" id="_agile_confirmation_msg" name="_agile_confirmation_msg" value="Thanks">
      <input type="hidden" id="_agile_form_id_tags" name="tags" value="Video Form">
      <input type="hidden" id="_agile_form_id" name="_agile_form_id" value="***">
    </div>
    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="agile-group">
      <label class="agile-label" for="First-Name">First Name</label>
      <div class="agile-field-xlarge agile-field">
        <input maxlength="250" id="First-Name" name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="agile-height-default">
      </div>
      <div class="agile-custom-clear"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="agile-group">
      <label class="agile-label" for="Last-Name">Last Name</label>
      <div class="agile-field-xlarge agile-field">
        <input maxlength="250" id="Last-Name" name="last_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="agile-height-default">
      </div>
      <div class="agile-custom-clear"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="agile-group">
      <label class="agile-label" for="agilefield-9">Email</label>
      <div class="agile-field-xlarge agile-field">
        <input maxlength="250" id="agilefield-9" name="email" type="email" placeholder="" class="agile-height-default" onfocusout="myFunction()">
      </div>
      <div class="agile-custom-clear"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Hidden input-->
    <div class="agile-group agile-hiddenEle-group">
      <label class="agile-label" for="agilefield-11">Company</label>
      <div class="agile-field-xlarge agile-field">
        <input id="agilefield-11" name="Company" type="text" value="" class="agile-height-default">
      </div>
      <div class="agile-custom-clear"></div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Many thanks, the ID's are generated with the spaces by the CRM when I created the form. Most of the form is generated by them, the only script I added was the MyFunction Script.
I will test this and see if it works, although if the CRM is looking for "First Name" as an ID, then I am not sure that "First-Name" will sync in.

Comment: @ecalpemos2000 Then you can only replace `getElementById("Surname")` with `getElementById("Last Name")` in your script.

Comment: Many thanks again, a simple error may be my problem.

Comment: @ecalpemos2000 always glad to help, I suggest you should take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Welcome to Stackoverflow!:)

Comment: I sure will and I will do what is needed. Thanks for the welcome.

Comment: IDs can contain whitespace. Classnames cannot. This is a typo type question